# RGBA don't work

Tags: html, css

HTML CODE:

```
<div class="item">
<img src="images/img.jpg">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
.item img:hover {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 
    }
```

When I hover the image nothing happens.
I am trying to give to the image some dark when someone hover it.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Most likely, when you're hovering over the image the background is changing behind the image. You just can't see it because you're using a .jpeg image (no transparency). https://jsfiddle.net/w6r6cp1o/

Comment: is this question are still on going?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your RGBA of course won't work because when you're hovering over the image, the only effect is your background behind the images. **Unless** you're using transparency image that will work!.

HTML

```
<div class="item">
<img src="https://www.petfinder.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/140272627-grooming-needs-senior-cat-632x475.jpg">
<p>Hello</p>
</div>

<br>

<!-----This section To let you know For PNG hover ---> 

<div class="image">Before</div>
<div class="image">
  <div class="color">
    After
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.item img{
  height:100px;
    border-radius: 10%;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.15);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.15);
    transform: scale(1.15);
    transition: transform 0.5s, -webkit-filter 0.5s,-moz-filter 0.5s,-ms-filter 0.5s,filter 0.5s;
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: gray;
    filter: gray; /* IE 6-9 */
}

.item img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.03);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.03);
    transform: scale(1.03);
    -webkit-filter: none;
    -moz-filter: none;
    -ms-filter: none;
    filter: none;
    -webkit-filter: none;
    filter: none; /* IE 6-9 */
    }

 /*-----This section To let you know For PNG hover ---*/   

    .image {
  background:url(http://nsood.in/logo256.png);
  width:256px;
  height:256px;
  display:inline-block;
}
.color:hover {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
  color:#fff;
}
```

Check out my [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/L2byqs9p/)

I show two output.

1. Control the image JPG using filter and opacity.
2. Using png file using RGBA.

Answer (score 0):

The background is *behind* the image, so you won't see it. You'd have to create  anther layer with that background that contains the `<img>`tag and has the same size, Then assing that background to this new layer on hover.

```
<div class="item">
  <div class="layer">
    <img src="images/img.jpg">
  </div>
  <p>Hello</p>
</div>


.layer:hover {
        background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8) 
    }
```